# CSS hover flicks the image below

Tags: jquery, html, css

My website has a problem. When I hover to a the fourth image, the images below falls apart, only on Mozilla but works perfectly fine with Chrome. I know its a CSS problem, I tried the `-moz-border-radius` but does not work. [Here is the link to the website](http://tradesansar.com) you could try it and here is a part of the CSS:

```
listsitemsbg {
    list-style:none;
    *zoom: 1;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.listsitemsbg li {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.listsitemsbg .thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1.98px solid #BE2121;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.listsitemsbg .thumbnail:hover {
    border: 0px solid #aaa;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px solid #aa   
}
.listsitemsbg .thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
}
.listsitemsbg .thumbssettingsbg > div {
    margin:0;
    border-bottom: 0px dotted #ccc;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the border in HOVER. Update the hover class as per below.

```
.listsitemsbg .thumbnail:hover {
    border: 1.98px solid #fff;
}
```

Even You can go with transparent border like below.

```
.listsitemsbg .thumbnail:hover {
    border: 1.98px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your hover state for thumbnail

```
.listsitemsbg .thumbnail:hover{
 border: 1.98px solid #aaa;
}
```